# How to Create Individual Instances of SQL Database for Different Items

Tags: android, sql, database

I am creating an Android app that requires two ListViews. One ListView contains a list of user created categories. When a user clicks on a specific category, they are then taken to another ListView that contains the contents of the category. My question is: how do I create a specific database for each of the categories. I have tried making a single SQL database, but when I click on different categories, their content is the same.

Let me know if I need to word this differently. I understand what I want to say, it's just saying it that is the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set up 2 tables in the same database, then use a different DATABASE_TABLE variable

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + record, null, null, null, null)

Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + record, null, null, null, null)
```

Comment: I tried to create two tables, one for the categories, and then one for the individual items in each category, but whenever I access a category, it has all of the saved information from the other categories, as well as its own.